# Highcharts(highstock), how to Pass the dates to the navigator

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to pass the dates to the Navigator, but by default the timestamp is passing to the navigator could any one please help me how to pass the dates to the navigator, i.e. as per dates that are there in x-axis.

```
this is the jsfiddle link : `http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/16/`
```

please find the jsfiddle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not sending in your data as time/value? This way `navigator` does this for you automatically? You have an array of strings for dates that you then parse in the `xAxis.label` function to display text - but your time in the data series is an integer starting from 0. Then you want to send in this modified date stamp into your navigator as a string? And you have duplicate values in your dates array. You are making much more work for yourself.

Send in data like below with your x as [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC):

```
series: [{
            name: 'RNA',
            data: [{
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 5, 14),
                y: 99.43,
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: Date.UTC(2014, 5, 19),
                y: 99.40,
                extprop: 'flood'
            }...
```

See update jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/hj22wbe5/17/). I assume you meant the time to go up without duplicates.

Comment: but in the x-axis also the values has to be dates ....how to pass the dates to the x-axis..please

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to navigator xaxis and use the same formatter, but better is using datetime type of xAxis as wergeld suggested.

```
navigator: {
            enabled: true,
             xAxis: {
            labels: {
                rotation: 90,
                align: "left",
                formatter: function () {
                    return dates[this.value];
                },
            },
            tickInterval: 1
        },
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/18/

Comment: Hi , Can you please help me with code...how can remove the base line in the navigator...?

Comment: Axis line, series line, gridline ?